# How to enable "View External Documentation" option in IntelliJ IDEA 14

Tags: java, intellij-idea

For a selected Java method I'm able to invoke the "Quick Documentation" option and view the JavaDoc in a popup windows. I'd like to be able to click the "View External Documentation" button (circled below), but the button is disabled. How do I enable it?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify the URL where the external documentation is located. For the JDK, it is configured under Project Structure | Platform Settings | SDKs | Documentation Paths.